# Split list of numbers (inc ranges) from single cell to column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a database with unique (numeric) identifiers; "ROL". e.g. 45

What I'd like is to be able to, in a single cell (C1), enter a list of ROLs, seperated by commas and for these to appear in a single column, with each row containing the ROLs from the list.

A simple example of this would be:

> 5,14,16,2

I also want there to be the option to input a range (14-19) and for the script to generate the ROL numbers from within the range (14,15,16,17,18,19) and add these to the rows accordingly.

```
function splitTest() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = activeSheet.getRange("c1").getValue();     //load in rols from cell
  Logger.log("Data "+ data);
  var array1 = data.split(",");  //split by ","
  var sheetarray = [];

    for (i = 0; i <= array1.length; i++) {      //loop though array data, i.e. separated rols
      var temp = array1[i];                     //array to store ROLS
      Logger.log("temp "+ temp);
      
      if(temp.includes("-")){
      //if(temp.indexOf("-") !==-1){
        var array2 = temp.split("-");

        for(i=array2[0];i<=array2[1];i++){     //loop between two rols seperated by "-"
          sheetarray.push(i);                 //push generated rol to array
          Logger.log("-push "+ i);
        }  
      }else{
        Logger.log("push "+ temp);
        sheetarray.push(temp);            //push single rol to array
      }
    }

    for(i=0;i<=sheetarray.length;i++){                                //loop array to send to rows
      var empty = activeSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();           //get length of rows, for last row  
      var lastcell = empty.filter(String).length+1;                   //gets legth of data array in column A, +1 for next empty
      activeSheet.getRange(lastcell,1).setValue(sheetarray[i]);
    }
    //Logger.log("sheet array= "+ sheetarray);
  
  
}
```

As of yet the code is partially working but I´m unsure where the mistake is.

When I run the code with

> 10,9,6-19,4

I get

> 10

> 9

But the script ends there.

When I try with

> 45,5,87,20-25

The output is correct.

The issue seems to be with single digit ranges.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample input and output situations on the Spreadsheet as the images?

Comment: @Tanaike
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HFpg3WUY6GM6Hc9zksRHUrvMGNC3rFhe_lN3S4cjYnQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- At `for (i = 0; i <= array1.length; i++) {`, the length of `array1` is over in the loop.
- The for loop of `for(i=array2[0];i<=array2[1];i++){`  is used in the for loop of `for (i = 0; i <= array1.length; i++) {`. In this case, please modify the variable name of `i` in the inner loop.
- When `var array2 = temp.split("-");` is used, the each value in `array2` is string.
- In order to use `10,9,6-19,4`, I think that it is required to sort the result array.
- When `setValue` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function splitTest() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = activeSheet.getRange("c1").getValue();
  var array1 = data.split(",");
  var sheetarray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    var temp = array1[i];
    if (temp.includes("-")) {
      var [start, end] = temp.split("-").map(Number);
      for (var j = start; j <= end; j++) {
        sheetarray.push([j]);
      }
    } else {
      sheetarray.push([Number(temp)]);
    }
  }
  activeSheet.getRange(activeSheet.getRange("A1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1, 0).getRow(), 1, sheetarray.length, sheetarray[0].length).setValues(sheetarray.sort((a, b) => a - b));
}
```

- In this modified script, when the value of cell "C1" is `1,3,5,7,09-15,20,25,30-35`, `1,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,20,25,30,31,32,33,34,35` is put to the column "A".

#### Note:

- As another direction, when you use the script as the custom function, I thought that the following sample script can be also used. In this case, please put a custom formula of `=SAMPLE(C1)` to a cell, the result is returned.

  ```
    const SAMPLE = value => value.split(",").flatMap(e => {
      const temp = e.trim();
      if (temp.includes("-")) {
        const [start, end] = temp.split("-").map(Number);
        const ar = [];
        for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
          ar.push([i])
        }
        return ar;
      }
      return [[Number(temp)]];
    }).sort((a, b) => a - b);
  ```

#### References:

- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: thanks your code works but as mentioned by @Daven Ramani the loop needs to run for array.length -1 times.

Comment: @Sebastián H Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, about your replying for my answer, I cannot understand about `but as mentioned by @Daven Ramani the loop needs to run for array.length -1 times.`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Sebastián H `for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {` is the same with `for (i = 0; i <= array1.length-1;i++) {`. And, in your script, the variable `i` is change by 2 for loops. I thought that this is also the modification point. And also, from `10,9,6-19,4` in your sample, I thought that `sort` is required to be used. I apologize for this.

Comment: I can't suggest the edit because it is too short, but it should be `sheetarray.push([j][0]);` otherwise it pushes an array with a single element

Comment: same thing for the script in $ Note: `ar.push([i][0])`

Comment: oh I get it now ^^ a 2D array is required for `setValues()`

Answer (score 1):

```
function splitTest() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = activeSheet.getRange("c1").getValue();     //load in rols from cell
  Logger.log("Data "+ data);
  var array1 = data.split(",");  //split by ","
  var sheetarray = [];

    for (i = 0; i <= array1.length-1;i++) {      //loop though array data, i.e. separated rols
      var temp = array1[i];                     //array to store ROLS
      Logger.log("temp "+ temp);
      
      if(temp.includes("-")){
      //if(temp.indexOf("-") !==-1){
        var array2 = temp.split("-");
        for(i=Number(array2[0]);i<=Number(array2[1]);i++){     //loop between two rols seperated by "-"
          sheetarray.push(i);                 //push generated rol to array
          Logger.log("-push "+ i);
        }  
      }else{
        Logger.log("push "+ temp);
        sheetarray.push(temp);            //push single rol to array
      }
    }

    for(i=0;i<=sheetarray.length-1;i++){                                //loop array to send to rows
      var empty = activeSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();           //get length of rows, for last row  
      var lastcell = empty.filter(String).length+1;                   //gets legth of data array in column A, +1 for next empty
      activeSheet.getRange(lastcell,1).setValue(sheetarray[i]);
    }
    //Logger.log("sheet array= "+ sheetarray);
  
  
}
```

Here is the updated code ... you need to cast your input as number while comparing in for loop.. also you need to run your for loop for arry.length -1 times

Comment: thanks, ive used a modification of your code to solve the issues I was having.